# How to inherit a required module in to GWT Project?

Tags: gwt

I want to use the GWT-FXv0.5.0MS_1.jar in my GWT Project, i added the jar file to project path and used the codes up on syntax, now am getting error that not inherited:
Error message is:

```
11:28:48.829 [ERROR] [uibuilder] Line 80: No source code is available for type org.adamtacy.client.ui.effects.core.NMorphStyle; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add inherit tag in your gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="com.company.gwt-fx"/>
```

Comment: When i add like this it shows error message : 

 [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/company/gwt-fx.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?



is this name in "" is correct?

Comment: This is because your gwt-fx.jar is not a gwt project jar.
So to use the jar in client side you have to convert it to a gwt jar by adding a gwt.xml to your jar.

create a new file : gwt-fx.gwt.xml

`<module rename-to='gwt-fx'> 
  <source path="package_name"></source>
</module>`

here replace the 'package_name' with the name of the package inside your jar file.

And finally put the gwt-fx.gwt.xml file inside the jar file relative to the package_name.

Comment: There already exist a file gwt.xml in that jar package, should i use that?
the path is:
org/adamtacy/GWTEffects.gwt.xml

Comment: then use this 
`<inherits name="org.adamtacy.GWTEffects"/>` inside your gwt.xml