# gwtbootstrap3 available at compile time but not at runtime?

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

question is about gwtbootstap3 error that I am receiving when trying to run my GWT application. Everything mentioned here [Initial Setup](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/wiki/Initial-Setup) is being done and my code compiles and gets installed using maven. Dependency scope is provided so should I manually copy jar to application server? I am using JBoss 6.1.0 Final. If JAR file needs to be copied manually, where do I put it? Below is error that I receive,

```
unning GPE launcher for GWT-2.6.x version.
Runing CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, com.HouseKeepingGWT]
workDir: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-1867973844823357957.tmp
Loading modules
   com.HouseKeepingGWT
      Loading inherited module 'com.HouseKeepingGWT'
         Loading inherited module 'org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3'
Loading inherited module 'com.HouseKeepingGWT'
            [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/gwtbootstrap3/GwtBootstrap3.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
   Loading inherited module 'org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3'
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/gwtbootstrap3/GwtBootstrap3.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
         [ERROR] Line 17: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
   [ERROR] Line 17: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:328)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:328)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
```

Looks like, JAR is not available at run time that is why I am receiving error. Please suggest. GwtBootstrap3.gwt.xml is in gwtbootstrap3 jar.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-shared-libs) for configuring JBoss shared libs folder (or find another one on the web, it shouldn't be too hard). However, why are you using the `provided` scope? If this application is the only one using gwtBootstrap you can remove it so that Maven can package the jar directly inside your application's war.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I had to build and run the project to fix some bugs while project had been configured by somebody else. I will try to find answer about putting that scope there.

Comment: Error remains even if I change scope to compile and jar is there in target war file.

Comment: Then the problem should be in the way you inherit the module. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251782/how-to-inherit-a-required-module-in-to-gwt-project) can help.

Comment: I am inheriting module the way its mentioned in Initial Setup link provided in my question. Hope to resolve error soon.